# How to make dropdown menus have shadow?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, customization

When I right-click on desktop, there's no shadow of menu. How can I make all dropdown menus have shadow?

Comment: You should answer your question with the solution you've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's a conflict between Nautilus Elementary and Compiz.

Solution:

- In Nautilus : select menu Edit->Preferences->Tweaks -> under Application uncheck "Enable rgba transparency".
- In CCSM : Enable Windows Decoration, at Windows shadow line, replace "any" with "any (class=Tooltip | Menu | PopupMenu | DropdownMenu | Unknown)" (without quotes).
- If there's still no shadow, restart Nautilus by typing this line in Terminal : "nautilus -q" (without quotes).

Hope it useful for someone who need!